# to search and replace the string in all db objects source code in oracle database

Tags: oracle

I wanted to search and replace DZONE to SZONE in all the database objects where it is being used. I have a query to search the DZONE using below query but dont know how to replace in code.

```
select name,text from user_source where text like '%DZONE';
```

Comment: This question kind of implies you're not using source control.  That's a pretty serious offense around here.  :)  See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html

Answer (score 4):

first get the ddl and spool it to a text file for you to review:

```
select regexp_replace (dbms_metadata.get_ddl (object_type, object_name, USER),'DZONE','SZONE') 
from (
select distinct object_name, object_type
 from user_procedures where object_name in (select name from user_source where text like '%DZONE%')
)
```

than apply the source to your database.
do this for the object types that you want to modify, in this example I only picked the stored procedures, packages and functions.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update the source of an object directly. You need to identify all the objects and recreate them with the modified text - either with an updated version of whatever DDL was used to create them in the first place, or if you don't have that, by extracting the full text, updating it, and then executing it. You could maybe do it with dynamic SQL but this seems a bit dangerous - personally I'd probably want to inspect and verify everything I was updating.

Answer (score 0):

I recently need to create such script. This is to replace wrong unicode characters on all database, so I start searching for Ã all around:

```sql
--text with encoding problems

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000

DECLARE
 CURSOR c1 IS
 SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
              FROM all_tab_columns
              WHERE owner = 'your-owner-name' and data_type LIKE '%CHAR%';
 --
 c1rec c1%ROWTYPE;
 --
 l_sql VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
 FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
    l_sql := 'DECLARE '||
             '   CURSOR c1 IS '||
             '   SELECT '||r1.column_name||
             '   FROM   '||r1.table_name||' WHERE '||r1.column_name||' like ''%Ã%''; '||
             '   c1rec c1%ROWTYPE; '||
             'BEGIN '||
             '   FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP '||
             '      dbms_output.put_line('''||r1.table_name||'.'||r1.column_name||': ''|| r1.'||r1.column_name||'); '||
             '   END LOOP; '||
             'END; ';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

that will print all word problems (modify owner or data type as you need)

Ok, but after that, you need to fix database (replace). Well that's just more fun with oracle pl/sql

```sql
--generating updates with encoding problems

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000

DECLARE
 CURSOR c1 IS
 SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
              FROM all_tab_columns
              WHERE owner = 'your-owner-name' and data_type LIKE '%CHAR%';
 --
 c1rec c1%ROWTYPE;
 --
 l_sql VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
 FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
    l_sql := 'DECLARE '||
             '   CURSOR c1 IS '||
             '   SELECT '||r1.column_name||
             '   FROM   '||r1.table_name||' WHERE '||r1.column_name||' like ''%Ã%''; '||
             '   c1rec c1%ROWTYPE; '||
             'BEGIN '||
             '   FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP '||
             '      dbms_output.put_line(''UPDATE '||r1.table_name||' SET '||r1.column_name||' = ''''''|| r1.'||r1.column_name||'||'''''' WHERE '||r1.column_name||' = ''''''|| r1.'||r1.column_name||'||'''''';''); '||
             '   END LOOP; '||
             'END; ';

    --dbms_output.put_line( l_sql );

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

that will output a series of update commands you should tweak with your fixes.

```sql
UPDATE PERSON SET NAME = 'Ã¿ângela' WHERE NAME = 'Ã¿ângela';
UPDATE ROOM SET DESCRIPCION = 'Sala de reparacÃ¿n' WHERE DESCRIPCION = 'Sala de reparacÃ¿n';
...
```

something like:

```sql
UPDATE PERSON SET NAME = 'Ángela' WHERE NAME = 'Ã¿ângela';
UPDATE ROOM SET DESCRIPCION = 'Sala de reparación' WHERE DESCRIPCION = 'Sala de reparacÃ¿n';
...
```

Depending on problem you could automate this part (if you manage to deal with the quote hell)

Hint: This is an update with a replace

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000

DECLARE
 CURSOR c1 IS
 SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
              FROM all_tab_columns
              WHERE owner = 'your-owner-name' and data_type LIKE '%CHAR%';
              --uncomment to shorten the search and debug
              --AND table_name = 'some-table'
 --
 c1rec c1%ROWTYPE;
 --
 l_sql VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
 FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
    l_sql := 'DECLARE '||
             '   CURSOR c1 IS '||
             '   SELECT '||r1.column_name||
             '   FROM   '||r1.table_name||' WHERE '||r1.column_name||' like ''%Ã¿%''; '||
             '   c1rec c1%ROWTYPE; '||
             'BEGIN '||
             '   FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP '||
             '      dbms_output.put_line(''UPDATE '||r1.table_name||' SET '||r1.column_name||' = REPLACE('||r1.column_name||',''''%Ã¿%'''',''''ó'''')''||'' WHERE '||r1.column_name||' = ''''''|| r1.'||r1.column_name||'||'''''';''); '||
             '   END LOOP; '||
             'END; ';

    --uncomment to debug         
    --dbms_output.put_line( l_sql );

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

which output something like:

```sql
UPDATE VEHICLE SET NAME = REPLACE(NAME,'%Ã¿%','ó') WHERE NAME = 'CamiÃ¿n';
```

Answer (score -3):

Use update query with where clause

```
Update user_source 
Set text = 'SZONE'
Where text like '%DZONE';
```

hopes that helps

Comment: Not sure trying up update internal Oracle views is a good idea, or would be allowed for a normal user. This wouldn't be right on a normal table either though, where `replace` would be needed - this loses any text before the `DZONE`.

Comment: On reflection, I'll rephrase that; attempting to update `USER_SOURCE` directly is definitely a bad idea.

Comment: -1; this is a real bad idea; we can not perform the updates this way. Very unsupported. Better is to generate the DDL and re-issue the modified DDL.

Comment: @ik_zelf  plz explain in detail not getting your point,  also provide better ans if have any

Comment: @imran the *_source views are supposed to be read only. Use dbms_metadata.get_ddl and replace the strings in the text that is returned. *_source should reflect the code for the objects, not with the intention to modify it directly.

Comment: @imran: you're trying to directly update the data dictionary, which is going to cause corruption and possibly render the database unusable. (I doubt it would let you update this view, even as `SYS`, but I'm not going to try!) The only safe way to change things is with supported DDL commands.

Comment: @imran: never EVER modify dictionary objects directly (through DML).

Comment: @Imran, the problem is - you *could* test this in a database where it doesn't matter if it gets destroyed, e.g. in a VM; but then you could never guarantee that the change doesn't introduce a significant problem elsewhere that your test doesn't pick up straight away. It's unsupported and very risky.

Comment: @imran, forgot to mention: I provided an answer of which I believe it is a good answer using the proper tools.